# How to improve load time of react native view in hybrid app

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, react-native

I have created a hybrid app where few screens(chat) are written in react native. I have followed `react-native integration with existing app` guidelines and have created an activity to start react application when my android activity is created. 
My activity code looks similar to,

```
public class MyReactActivity extends Activity implements 
    DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(getApplication());
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModulePath("index")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyReactNativeApp", null);

        setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
      super.onBackPressed();
   }
}
```

Problem with this approach is that, React application is created every time `MyReactActivity` is created and this process takes 1-2 seconds. Even when user press's back and comes back to this activity, it will start react application again. I want to reduce this load time.

If I slightly modify above code and change ReactRootView and ReactInstanceManager to static. It uses same ReactRootView and InstanceManager, every time I create my activity. This definitely improves load time for my activity but may lead to bad performance. New Activity code is similar to,

```
public class MyReactActivity extends Activity implements 
    DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    private static ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    private static ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(mReactRootView != null) {
            return;
        }
        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(getApplication());
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModulePath("index")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyReactNativeApp", null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
      if (mReactRootView != null) {
          ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mReactRootView.getParent();
          if(parent != null) {
              parent.removeView(mReactRootView);
          }
      }
      super.onStop();
   }

    @Override
    public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
      if (mReactRootView != null) {
          ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mReactRootView.getParent();
          if(parent != null) {
              parent.removeView(mReactRootView);
          }
      }
      super.onBackPressed();
   }
}
```

This approach seems to be working fine but I think, it might result in memory leak as the static reference to ReactRootView and ReactInstanceManager will always keep them in memory. Surprisingly, I don't see any memory leak when I run analyzer task for memory monitor.

Does anyone have any suggestion on this? Is it ok to use static reference? Is there any other way of optimizing load time of react app every time I load my activity?

Thanks!

Comment: And of course you test it with "don't keep activities" on? no? then you should ...

Comment: Honestly, I was not aware of any such option. Thanks to you I just tested and everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The approach you are following is in the right direction.

The docs mention that you can have a single ReactInstanceManager instance using a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

> A ReactInstanceManager can be shared amongst multiple activities and/or fragments. You will want to make your own ReactFragment or ReactActivity and have a singleton holder that holds a ReactInstanceManager. When you need the ReactInstanceManager (e.g., to hook up the ReactInstanceManager to the lifecycle of those Activities or Fragments) use the one provided by the singleton.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps